# Codable Handle Single or Array

Tags: ios, swift, codable

Our API sends single object in data when the array contains one element:

```
{
  "data":{
    "name":"ABC",
    "age":"26"
  }
}
```

But when there are more elements in array then the response is in array

```
{
  "data":[{
    "name": "ABC",
    "age" : "26"
  },
  {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "age" : "22"
  }]
}
```

Comment: While decoding the response with Json decoder , you have to specify a type. A single decoding cannot work for the above two scenarios, it will be very easy if the API returns an array in the first scenario also.

Comment: @Shubham Sadly API's cannot be changed so have to find way to handle this scenario.

Comment: I see, you can use @Sh_khan's answer to decode the data if there is no way to fix the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
struct Root  : Codable {

   let data:[DItem]

   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    do {
         data = try container.decode([DItem].self, forKey: .data)
    }
    catch {
         let res = try container.decode(DItem.self, forKey: .data)
        data = [res]
    }

 }
}

struct DItem: Codable {
   let name,age:String 
}
```

---

```
let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from:data)
```

until you fix the response

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a bad API design to me.

Your API should return an array in your `data` field whatever the count.

`{ "data":[{ "name": "XYZ", "age" : "22" }] }`

or

`{ "data":[{ "name": "ABC", "age" : "26" }, { "name": "XYZ", "age" : "22" }] }`